# Concatenate fields in one Facet

Tags: solr, typo3, facet

i have some fields in my Solr index containing boolean values. I want to use them in one facet, not in separate ones. How can i achieve this.

The fields are like this in the solr index:

- isGuaranteed_boolS
- isApproved_boolS
- isFavorite_boolS

thanks
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A facet shows the distinct values that occur in a single field within the current result set and allows you to filter the result set on one or more of those values. I don't see an option to do that for three fields in one facet. 
What you could do is to create an extra multi value field that contains labels representing each of those fields. Just see each boolean field as a tag or label and store those labels in the extra field.

Comment: Hi Jigal, thx for your answer. That's how i did it in the end.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as the correct answer, please? Then it shows up in lists as "answered" and might help others. Thanks!